# Define Path for secret in Hashicorp not work with Quarkus

Tags: kubernetes, quarkus, hashicorp-vault, vault

I have this error when I deploy my app:

[image]

My properties are these:

```html
quarkus.vault.secret-config-kv-path=kv2/dev/test/test/getting-started-v1
quarkus.vault.kv-secret-engine-version=2
quarkus.vault.authentication.kubernetes.role=getting-started-v1
```

My policy in hashicorp is the same and the role is attached for this policie.

When I disabled this property: `quarkus.vault.secret-config-kv-path` the app running but not load any secrets this is the console message:

[image]

I have used this [documentation](https://quarkiverse.github.io/quarkiverse-docs/quarkus-vault/dev/vault-auth.html#_kubernetes_authentication)

Any help or idea for get the values for hashicorp, probably other method programmatic

Answer (score 0):

This could be a typical issue with kv ver 1 vs 2. Ver 2 has different path. You should consider it in your settings and policy, check the document: https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/secrets-management/versioned-kv#compare-kv-v1-and-kv-v2

In most cases you need to add `data` after a mount point in the path: `kv2/data/dev/test/test...`

Comment: Thanks for help. I found the solution configuring this property kv-secret-engine-mount-path and with this value my app got the secrets.